# Vendor metrics from Clikhouse to grafana

Tags: grafana, clickhouse

Good day everyone, I ran into such a problem while adding monitors to grafana with metrics on the status of requests from our suppliers to the clickhouse database.
I need suppliers whose status = 200 or! = 200 to return to the schedule.

We want that when the condition - count (CASE WHEN StatusRes! = '200' THEN 1 END) is fulfilled, we will display the data of suppliers that have a request status not 200, but if - count (CASE WHEN StatusRes 0 = '200' THEN 1 END ) only suppliers with request status 200.

But in fact, the request is processed incorrectly (all statuses are returned both 200 and 500) and I do not know why.

Here is the query itself, which we will use in grafana to take metrics:

```
    SELECT
    $timeSeries as t,
    StatusRes,
    count(CASE WHEN StatusRes != '200' THEN 1 END),
    count(CASE WHEN StatusRes == '200' THEN 1 END),
    Provider
FROM $table

WHERE $timeFilter

GROUP BY
    t,
    StatusRes,
    Provider
ORDER BY
    t,
    StatusRes,
    Provider
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`count( col )`  -- counts number of **ROWS** where col **is not null**. It's not about CH, it's ANSI SQL.

You actually should use countIf

```
    StatusRes,
    countIf(StatusRes != '200'),
    countIf(StatusRes == '200'),
    Provider
```

Or sum

```
    sum(StatusRes != '200'),
    sum(StatusRes == '200'),
```

---

```
create table XX(a Int64, StatusRes String) Engine=Memory;

INSERT INTO XX SELECT
    number,
    ['200', '500', '400'][(rand() % 3) + 1]
FROM numbers(1000);


SELECT
    sum(StatusRes = '200'),
    sum(StatusRes != '200')
FROM XX

┌─sum(equals(StatusRes, '200'))─┬─sum(notEquals(StatusRes, '200'))─┐
│                           321 │                              679 │
└───────────────────────────────┴──────────────────────────────────┘



SELECT
    countIf(StatusRes = '200'),
    countIf(StatusRes != '200')
FROM XX
┌─countIf(equals(StatusRes, '200'))─┬─countIf(notEquals(StatusRes, '200'))─┐
│                               321 │                                  679 │
└───────────────────────────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Comment: thanks, the example with "sum (StatusRes! = '200')" worked for me. But with countif it didn't work out. Tell me more please, but how can I make the percentage of statuses 200 and 500?

Comment: I updated my reply with an example. I don's see why sum and countIf can give different results.

Comment: Hello, now works for me with sum value too. thank you