# How to count the same lines only once in CASE? SQL

Tags: sql, case, clickhouse

I have table with id, time and event(A or B). I need to write a case(or another condition), which find in table entry where event='B' and count it once, group by id.

For example,
for id 1: the table has line with event B, so counter 1.
for id 2: the table has line with event B, so counter 1.
for id 3: the table has not line with event B, so counter 0.
for id 4: the table has line with event B, so counter 1.

And then it counts percentage, in my example it will be (1+1+0+1)*100/4 = 75%

| id | DateTime | event |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-04-01 15:00:00 | A |
| 1 | 2021-04-01 15:00:00 | B |
| 1 | 2021-04-01 15:00:00 | B |
| 2 | 2021-04-01 21:00:00 | A |
| 2 | 2021-04-05 21:00:00 | B |
| 3 | 2021-04-05 10:00:00 | A |
| 1 | 2021-04-07 15:00:00 | B |
| 4 | 2021-04-10 17:00:00 | A |
| 4 | 2021-04-11 17:00:00 | B |
| 4 | 2021-04-11 17:00:00 | B |

Comment: Please provide more explanation and the results you want.

Comment: [Edit] the question and provide a [example], i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables or other objects involved (paste the **text**, don't use images, don't link to external sites), `INSERT` statements for sample data (dito) and the desired result with that sample data in tabular text format. Show what you have tried already. Explain why/where it failed. Be specific (error message, unexpected result, etc.).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67828913/11644308

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```sql
SELECT
    uniq(id) AS uniqEventCount,
    uniqIf(id, event = 'B') AS uniqBEventCount,
    (uniqBEventCount * 100) / uniqEventCount AS percentage
FROM (
  /* emulate the test dataset */
  SELECT data.1 AS id, data.2 AS DateTime, data.3 AS event
  FROM (
    SELECT arrayJoin([
      (1, '2021-04-01 15:00:00', 'A'),
      (1, '2021-04-01 15:00:00', 'B'),
      (1, '2021-04-01 15:00:00', 'B'),
      (2, '2021-04-01 21:00:00', 'A'),
      (2, '2021-04-05 21:00:00', 'B'),
      (3, '2021-04-05 10:00:00', 'A'),
      (1, '2021-04-07 15:00:00', 'B'),
      (4, '2021-04-10 17:00:00', 'A'),
      (4, '2021-04-11 17:00:00', 'B'),
      (4, '2021-04-11 17:00:00', 'B')]) as data))

/*
┌─uniqEventCount─┬─uniqBEventCount─┬─percentage─┐
│              4 │               3 │         75 │
└────────────────┴─────────────────┴────────────┘
*/
```